# How to get the formatted POST data of a Django form?

Tags: jquery, django, forms, post

I have a Django ModelForm but don't want the user to click on a reguar submit button.
Instead, I made my own submit button and will post the form data using Ajax/jQuery.
The data to post is a mix of the form data plus other information I gather on my UI.
But... how do i get the formatted POST data the html form was supposed to submit?
If I can get it like JSON or jQuery object, better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for this which you in turn can pass as 2nd argument of [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

```
$('#formid').submit(function() {
    $.post('serverUrl', $(this).serialize(), callbackFunction);
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for this, which makes stuff easier.

Comment: Good! But I need to mix this serialized with other object like {param1:1, param2:2}
Another problem is that when I create a <form> object, whenever I call $.post(), it will actually post my form, reloading the page, which is no good!

Comment: 1. Well you can get `$(this).serialize()` into a javascript object before the post call, and add fields manually to it; 2. Really, no it doesn't. `$.post` is an AJAX submit, and `return false` means that the form's default submit action is not carried out.

Comment: @Roger, @Daniel is right. Do something like `var data = $(this).serialize(); data.param1 = 1;`. The `return false;` should block form's default action.

Comment: I was missing the `return false;`, not it won't submit! I'm posting something like this... `$.param(myparams) + "&" + $('#form_id').serialize();`. Thanks!!